# How does $F(\psi, \phi) = [\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}]^{2}$

Tags: information-theory, fidelity

From Quantum Information Theory by Mark Wilde, pg 243 asks to show that $F(\psi, \phi) = [\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}]^{2}$, which is described as the Bhattacharyya overlap, or classical fidelity, between distributions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. However, anywhere I look it up, said overlap is given as $\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}$. No square is involved. Moreover, I am unsure if the means by which I arrive at this is correct?

For $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)}|x\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle = \sum_{x}\sqrt{q(x)}|x\rangle$, where $|x\rangle$ is an orthonormal basis, if get:

$$F(\psi,\phi)=|\langle \psi|\phi\rangle|^{2}=\sqrt{\langle \psi|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|\psi\rangle}^{2}= \sqrt{\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)}\sqrt{q(x)}\sum_{x}\sqrt{q(x)}\sqrt{p(x)}}^{2}=$$
$$ 
=\sqrt{\left(\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}\right)^{2}}^{2}=\left(\sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}\right)^{2}$$

This looks right, but it's not equal to the overlap it is supposedly equivalent to, and I wonder if I have made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a difference in definition. For example the fidelity defined in Nielsen and Chuang is
$$
F(\rho, \sigma) = \text{tr}\sqrt{\rho^{1/2} \sigma \rho^{1/2}}
$$
which for pure states becomes

\begin{align}
F(\psi, \phi) &= \text{tr}\sqrt{|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| \phi\rangle\langle\phi| \psi\rangle\langle\psi|} \\
&=\sqrt{\langle\psi| \phi\rangle\langle\phi| \psi\rangle}\cdot\text{tr}\sqrt{|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|} \\
&= |\langle \psi|\phi \rangle|
\end{align}
and this definition is consistent with the formula you recovered for Bhattacharyya distance between distributions, $BC(p, q) \equiv \sum_{x}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}$ (see Nielsen and Chuang, eqn 9.2).

If you replace $F(\psi, \phi)= |\langle \psi|\phi \rangle|$ with $F'(\psi, \phi)= |\langle \psi|\phi \rangle|^2 = F(\psi, \phi)^2$ which appears to be definition that the author is using, then you will instead derive $F'(\psi, \phi) = BC(p, q)^2$ as you have done.